# Need help for Dynamic Method Dispatch Example

Tags: java, inheritance

I need help with this Java Program example. This example is from the book 
Java: Seventh Edition by Herbert Schildt.

I have few doubts about this program and also doubts about the text(explanation of this topic) written in this book. This program is written under Inheritance --> Method Overriding. Here A is the super class of B and B is the super class of C. In this program callme() is a method written in the three classes where each callme() overides another callme() method.

> 1) In the program below, what does obtain a reference of type A means? (This concept is  implemented in the line A r; in the Main method)
>   2) What is name space convention?
>   3) In this program, what does "r referes to an A object mean"? (This concept is implemented in the lines r.callme(); written in the main method.)

```
class A
{
void callme()
{
System.out.println("Im in the class A");
}
}

class B extends A
{
void callme()
{
System.out.println("Im in the class B");
}
}

class C extends B
{
void callme()
{
System.out.println("Im in the class C");
}
}

public class Dispatch 
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
A a = new A();
B b = new B();
C c = new C();
A r;

r = a;
r.callme();
r = b;
r.callme();
r = c;
r.callme();
}
}
```

Comment: What is your question?  Can you explain what happens when you runt he program?  I don't see any dynamic dispatch, your calls will all be invoked virtually.

Comment: This program was explained in the book that I mentioned in the question. The output of the above program is:  Im in classA Im in classB and Im in classC

Comment: This is what you would expect.  I still haven't worked out what your question is.

Comment: Im the main method, there is a line -->  A r; --> There is a comment written beside this line --> obtain a reference of type A. What does this mean?

Comment: I can't see the comment, however a reference is just a way to lookup an object. The default value is `null` i.e. no object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a way to overcome the problem of method over-riding.
If you want to get rid of method over-ridden at some time during your development then you can use this way of DMD.

Referring your example with comments:

```
class A //Super class A
{
    void callme()   // method callme() that'll be overwritten next in subclasses
    {
        System.out.println("Im in the class A"); 
    }
}  
class B extends A   //Subclass B  inherited from A
{            
    void callme()   //method callme() of Super class A is over-hided here
    {
        System.out.println("Im in the class B"); 
    } 
}  
class C extends B            //Subclass C, inherited from B
{
    void callme()    // this time B subclass method callme() is over-hided
    {
        System.out.println("Im in the class C"); 
    }
}  

//Now suppose, during you development phase at some time, you don't want to use over-ridden methods, here is DMD to help you out at run time.

public class Dispatch
{ 
    public static void main(String args[])
    { 
        A a = new A(); 
        B b = new B(); 
        C c = new C(); 
        A r;
        // r is a reference to class A
        // this reference should be assigned to each type of object and called at
        // run time without compiling.
        r = a; 
        r.callme(); 
        r = b; r.callme(); 
        r = c; r.callme(); 
    } 
}
```